# What units are in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm stuck on this question.

I know how to find the units of rings for example, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$.  I need to find elements that are relatively prime to $7$ and $15$. Having trouble with the product example.

Comment: Can you find at least one to get started?

Comment: First: what is the multiplicative unit element in $\;\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z\;$ ? Next, can you find a non unity unit in this ring?

Answer (score 1):

Taking group of units preserves products, that's
\begin{align}
((\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times\Bbb Z)^\times
&=(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^\times\times\Bbb Z^\times\\
&=\{1+2\Bbb Z\}\times\{\pm 1\}
\end{align}
hence the units of $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times\Bbb Z$ are $(1+2\Bbb Z,\pm 1)$.